# installed module on python editor

Tags: python, editor

how can i import modules/packages at python3.0 editor IDLE.
and can we see all the  modules contain/included  by it.

Comment: Does the import statement work?  Does the dir() function work?

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import idle
>>> dir(idle)
```